# How to use multiple functions in having clause

Tags: oracle10g

I am having problem while using having value.
The query I write in having clause is:

```
sum(min(nvl(qty,0)))>0
```

I get error:

> 'group function nested too deeply'

Comment: You need to provide more information - what does the rest of the query look like?

Comment: What would a `sum` of a `min` in a `having` clause do?  There would be only one `min` of a group so there would be nothing to `sum`.